# Binding iOS Library error with objective-c pointer?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

1.there is a pointer parameter in objective-c library

```
(CLLocationCoordinate2D* coords)
```

but the generated code do not have the pointer.

it should be an array but in generated code it is not.

the parameter `CLLocationCoordinated2D` should be an array.

how to fix it?
[image]

the issue url is https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14468

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below

```
   //ApiDefinition.cs
    [Static][Export ("polylineWithCoordinates:count:")][Internal]
 MGLPolyline PolylineWithCoordinates (IntPtr coords, nuint count);

// Extra.cs
public partial class MGLPolyline
{
    public static unsafe MGLPolyline PolylineWithCoordinates(CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords)
    {
        MGLPolyline line = null;

        fixed(void* arrPtr = coords)
        {

            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(arrPtr);
            line = MGLPolyline.PolylineWithCoordinates(ptr, 2);   
        }

        return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, glad that I can help.

Comment: Zhu thank you .say hello to LeonLu and Colex